# center a dropdown navigation

Tags: menu, navigation, dropdown, centering

I have searched endlessly for a solution to centering my drop-down navigation bar on my website.

I have tried removing the code float: left code from my CSS and added the code display: inline-block: but nothing seems to be working. I have tried several solutions but they have either moved my navigation bar from the top or removed the background I have set for the navigation bar.

If I could get some help on centering the navigation bar without removing the navigation bar's background or displacing it, that would be great.

```css
    html {
      background-image: url(../images/RL_bg.gif);
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    li {
      float: left;
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    li a, .dropbtn {
      display: inline-block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    li.dropdown {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Rocket League</title>
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <header>
            <ul>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Homepage</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="gameinfo.html">What is Rocket League?</a>
                        <a href="gameplay.html">Gameplay</a>
                        <a href="plat.html">Platforms</a>
                    </div>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Cars</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="stdcar.html">Standard</a>
                        <a href="dlc.html">Downloadable Content</a>
                        <a href="platexc.html">Platform Exclusive</a>
                    </div>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Online Content</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="mult.html">Multiplayer</a>
                        <a href="comp.html">Competitve</a>
                    </div>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Maps</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="std.html">Standard</a>
                        <a href="exp.html">Experimental</a>
                    </div>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Crates</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="itemcust.html">Item Customization</a>
                        <a href="trading.html">Trading</a>
                    </div>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">About Me</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="purpose.html">Purpose of This Site</a>
                        <a href="aboutme.html">About The Creator</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul> 
    </header>
    <body>
        <h1></h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your going to want to make a create a id for your ul's that does this tag around your entire list. Then you can use this for css.

```
 #navmenu {
       margin: 0 auto;
       width: 500px;
     }

 #navmenu a {
        width: 100px;
        text-align: center;
       }
```

So this will work if your using an inline list. Let me know if this solution is helpful at all, because we can custom taylor it to your css/html specifically.